# Need Qt QPA and X11 clarification

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, x11, xcb

I tried to understand Qts platform handling for hours now, but I dont get it. For my hotkey handling I currently use a mixture of X11extras for getting display, xlib for key conversions and xcb for the Qt native event handling. Three libs to link. And where does the undocumented QPA play a role here? Now I wonder if this is necessary. I need some clarification here. I am using qt 5.4. What is the way to go for the future?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Qt dev list?

Answer (score 0):

For Qt, you shouldn't need to do any native platform coding for key events unless you're using native windows. Read about [QEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) and the event functions in `QWidget`.

Use [QWidget::nativeEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) or [QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#installNativeEventFilter) if you need direct access to raw X11 events. Native event filters at the application level are processed for every event and have more of a performance impact than subclassing `QWidget` and reimplementing `nativeEvent()`.

Read about [QWindow::fromWinId()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId) and `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` if you need to embed a native window as a child widget.

Comment: Do you really expect me to accept this anser? There are plenty features not covered by Qt. So well I have to bother with native events. And further more I want to understand whats happening.

Comment: Apologies; from what you were discussing (key events, Qt event handling), I misunderstood. Can you clarify what you're trying to do? It will help me nail down my answer for you. QPA is not public yet, by the way. It's all private "until the API stabilizes", though we've heard that since 5.0.